# Error updating Android studio to 3.1.2

Tags: android-studio-3.1

When I try to update to Android Studio 3.1.2 the following message appears:

> An unexpected error occurred when preparing the patch Erro nos dados
>   (verificação cíclica de redundância)
>
> No files were changed; retry applying the patch.

Follows the log:

```
07/06 15:24:49 ERROR Runner.install - prepare failed
java.io.IOException: Erro nos dados (verificação cíclica de redundância)
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at com.intellij.updater.Digester.doDigestStream(Digester.java:121)
at com.intellij.updater.Digester.digestStream(Digester.java:114)
at com.intellij.updater.Digester.digestRegularFile(Digester.java:66)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.digestFile(Patch.java:485)
at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.isModified(PatchAction.java:197) 
at 
com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.doValidateNotChanged(PatchAction.java:167)
at com.intellij.updater.ValidateAction.validate(ValidateAction.java:38)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.lambda$validate$0(Patch.java:334)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:473)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.validate(Patch.java:333)
at 
com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.prepareAndValidate 
(PatchFileCreator.java: 69)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner.install(Runner.java:344)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner.main(Runner.java:133)
```